# Is there a way to change the whole document with one selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to change the font for the *whole* page in HTML. By whole I mean everything: buttons, forms, etc. Is there a way to do this in CSS?

```
html {
    color: green;
}
```

This would make the text green, but not the text of buttons.

Comment: Have you considered using LESS?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector):

```
* {
  color: green;
}
```

Take note, though, that specificity of this selector is the lowest ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)).

Comment: The universal selector doesn't have *any* specificity, just like the other combinators.

Comment: Anything else will overwrite `*` so to be sure the `color:green;` of `*` will be applied, use `color:green !important;`.

Comment: @raina77ow: As you can see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) the universal selector has a specificity of 0

Comment: Recommending `!important` to solve the styling problems is really like recommending pulling a tooth out when it aches. It does work, but it's rarely the best solution.

Comment: Does this mean that I should use !important along with this?

Comment: It really depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: `!important` has it's uses. If it's miss used then it's not a good solution. It is made as an over ride when needed.

Comment: Anything is fine if used correctly. Unfortunately, as with too many things, 'used correctly' is usually NOT the case with '!important'. [This article](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) (and the following discussion even more so) summarizes the reasoning behind it quite well.

Comment: MDN isn't technically wrong about universal selectors - the universal selector is the least specific of all the selectors. Zero is the lowest - there isn't a selector with negative specificity. (Unless you want to count HTML presentational attributes as "selectors", then you could say those have negative specificity because a `*` rule will override those.) It *does* misleadingly list classes, attributes and pseudo-classes separately, when they're all actually equally specific.

Answer (score 2):

Wild card selector

```
* {
    color: green;
}
```

It may be the case that you need to over ride inline CSS and javascript generated CSS. In this case use `!important` as well

```
* {
        color: green !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*` universal `CSS` selector.

The universal selector matches any element type. It can be implied (and therefore omitted) if it isn’t the only component of the simple selector.

The selector div `*` will match the following em elements:

- "Universal" in the h1 element ( matches the `<h1>` )
- "emphasize" in the p element ( matches the `<p>` )
- "not” in the first li element (matches the `<ul>` or the `<li>`)
- "type” in the second li element (matches the `<ul>` or the `<li>`)

Example:

`This rule set will be applied to every element in a document:`

```
* {
  color: green;
}
```

Also to add, it's compatible with most browsers, although it can be buggy in `Internet Explorer 5.5, 6.0, 7.0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE < 8, and want something that's less [smelly](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html), set an explicit color only on `html` and force everything else to *inherit* the color. Colors are already inherited by default on most elements, but not all of them.

Since this means applying two different `color` declarations, you will need two separate rules:

```
html {
    color: green;
}

body * {
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you shouldn't rely on a wildcard selector for doing this. You should take advantage of CSS's native inheritance. The best thing to do would be to remove the specific color declarations from your stylesheet (as needed) and add the color to your body or html tag. Using a wildcard is similar to this, except you are declaring that every single element should have the CSS as apposed to the native inheritance.

Comment: The problem here is that when you do that, it doesn't apply to buttons and forms and such.

Comment: If you are just trying to override the styles without changing any of the styles that are already in place, a wildcard selector with an !important modifier will work. Also, if you are worried about cross-browser you might run into issues. See here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/universalselector#compatibilitysection